How to catch the exception stacktrace in Firemonkey mobile app run-time?
Is there anything to easily catch human readable stack traces from exceptions happened on android/ios applications?
I can log exception classname and message. Provided human made log trace (how user went here) helps with getting in situation around where error may occur. But this doesn't help a lot, only telling that something is happened somewhere here. Even not always possible debug application on real device.
For windows we have a lot: jclDebug, madEcept, EurekaLog
any good news for firemonkey mobile application development?
How to get exception stack there? Filling that I get back into 2000 age.
IDE: Delphi 11.3 (Alexandria) or 12.1 (Athens)
